# Why does the rxjs share operator not work as expected when the observable is in service

Tags: typescript, rxjs, rxjs-pipeable-operators

I try to use **rxjs share operator** in two different ways.

1. *Using it in the component*

**Component:**

```
constructor() {
    const obs1 = interval(1000).pipe(
      tap(x => console.log('processing in comp1')),
      map(x => x * x),
      take(1),
      share()
    );

    obs1.subscribe(x=>console.log('testShare1'))
    obs1.subscribe(x=>console.log('testShare2'))
  }
```

Result:

```
processing in comp1  
testShare1
testShare2
```

It works as expected.

2. *Calling it from an external service.*

**Service:**

```
export class TestShareService {
  constructor() { }
  testShare() {
    const obs1 = interval(1000).pipe(
      tap(x => console.log('processing in service ')),
      map(x => x * x),
      take(1),
      share()
    );

    return obs1;
  }
}
```

**Component:**

```
constructor(private shareSrv: TestShareService) {
    shareSrv.testShare().subscribe(x=>console.log('testShare1 using service'));
    shareSrv.testShare().subscribe(x=>console.log('testShare2 using service'));

   }
```

result:

```
processing in service  
testShare1 using service
processing in service  
testShare2 using service
```

It looks like **rxjs share operator** does not affect when the observable is in an external service.
Is is right? Or what am I doing wrong?

Thank you.

Comment: Calling `testShare` returns an entirely new object each time. Has nothing to do with RXJS, thats just how JavaScript works.

Comment: Thank you. I indeed realized that when the observable  is a global field in TestShareService, It works fine! so, Is it the right way, to set the observable as a service global private field, and not to set it in "testShare" function?

Answer (score 1):

You need to assign the observable to a property on the service rather than create a new one with a function call.

```
export class TestShareService {
  private params$ = new BehaviorSubject<ParamsType | null>(null);
  
  data$ = params$.pipe(
    filter(params => params !== null), // filter out the initial null
    switchMap(params => this.http.get<YourResponseType>(params)),
    share()
  );

  get(params: ParamsType) {
    this.params$.next(params);
  }

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}
}
```

Now any subscriber to the observable data$ will be sharing the same instance of the same observable rather than a new observable each time the function is called. Any time the get function is called it will trigger the chain to make another http call.

Comment: In my real situation the observable is an httpRequest, and the method gets some arguments for the request , so I still don't know how to use a single instance. (The share suppose to be used when the request, including the arguments are the same)
`obs1$ = this.http.get(url+parameters).pipe(
    tap(x => console.log('processing in service ')),
    map(x => x * x),
    share()
  );`

Comment: I have edited the service to show you how you can switch map from a behavior subject to a http request and then share the response with multiple subscribers. Maybe have a read of this artile I wrote about a helper library I made for built data services like this https://adrianbrand.medium.com/angular-state-management-using-services-built-with-ez-state-9b23f16fb5ae